# No less a man then

Tags: sentence-meaning

In the book *Concepts of space* by Max Jammer, page 129, I see this sentence:

> Indeed, no less a man then Leonhard Euler grappled with the problem
>   for more than thirty years.

I want to learn what does "no less a man then" means here.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase should be "No less a man **than**" (not *then*). It means the same as "A man as great / important / capable as..." It is more politically correct to say ["No less a person than"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-less-a-person-than).

The phrase is being used to emphasize how difficult the problem was. It was so difficult that it took 30 years of working on it for a mathematician as great as Euler (one of the cleverest mathematicians in history) to solve it. (Or did he finally give up?!)

Comment: "Then" must by a typographical error. The phrase is a comparison : "No more than... no less than..." Yes the phrase is standard English. A little old-fashioned but standard all the same.